# Solve set of modular equations in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, linear-algebra, equation-solving

I am working on Quadratic Sieve algorithm in c++. And after Gaussian elimination I need to solve set of modular equations such as, for example :

```
(1) b + c = 0 mod 2
(2) a + c = 0 mod 2
```

Here the symbol = is used to mean "is congruent to". I am processing matrix as shown here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289348/matrix-processing-in-the-quadratic-sieve?rq=1.  If anyone has any ideas how to implement such a function that will solve these equations I would appreciate it.

Comment: The integers modulo 2 form a field, so the usual techniques will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite this system in matrix notation:

```
   M   . X  =  S 

|0 1 1|.|a| = |0|
|1 0 1| |b|   |0|
        |c|
```

Then you solve it as usual using Gaussian elimination. The small difference is that you only work with the values `0` and `1` and that substracting a row is the same as adding the row (in Z/2Z, -a = a)